# Get directory creation date as TDateTime

Tags: date, delphi, directory, creation

I'm wondering, how can I get a folder's creation date as a `TDateTime`?

`FileAge()` does not work with folders, only files, so sadly `datetime := FileDateToDateTime(FileAge())` won't work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a bit stumped here.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`TDirectory.GetCreationTime`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetCreationTime).

Comment: Which internally just returns the `CreationTime` from `SysUtils.FileGetDateTimeInfo()`.

Comment: And? The point is it has a cleaner API and is less cumbersome to use.

Comment: On the other hand, it raises an exception if the input parameter is invalid (including if the directory is not found), but it returns `0.0` if `FileGetDateTimeInfo()` fails, so the caller would have to handle both types of failures separately.  I wouldn't necessarily call that "less cumbersome".

Answer (score 1):

The version of [`FileAge()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileAge) you are calling is deprecated (the compiler should be warning you about that). You should be using the newer overload that has a `TDateTime` output parameter:

```pascal
function FileAge(const FileName: string; out FileDateTime: TDateTime; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
```

For example:

```pascal
if FileAge(path, datetime) then
begin
  // use datetime ...
end;
```

In any case, both versions of `FileAge()` use the Win32 [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) and/or [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) APIs internally, which both work just fine with folders, it is just that `FileAge()` filters the output to ignore folders.

So, just use those Win32 APIs directly instead.  Or, you can use the RTL's [`FileGetDateTimeInfo()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileGetDateTimeInfo) function instead:

```pascal
function FileGetDateTimeInfo(const FileName: string; out DateTime: TDateTimeInfoRec; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
```

[`TDateTimeInfoRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TDateTimeInfoRec) has a [`CreationTime`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TDateTimeInfoRec.CreationTime) property of type `TDateTime`.

For example:

```pascal
var
  info: TDateTimeInfoRec;

if FileGetDateTimeInfo(path, info) then
begin
  datetime := info.CreationTime;
  // use datetime ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, works nicely! One last questin however, how can you adjust the datetime to match that of Windows? It seems to be an hour difference when I test here, I think I need to call a Win32 API for this to make it system time?

Comment: `FileAge()` and `FileGetDateTimeInfo()` return dates in local time, but the original dates reported by the Win32 APIs are in UTC time.